# What is the best way to prevent implicit conversion of integer 0 to pointer in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

I am trying to figure out the best way to prevent integer 0 from being implicitly cast to nullptr_t and then passed to constructors that take pointers.  Explicit doesn't do it, but I can get nullptr_t to cause an ambiguous overload error:

```
#include <typeinfo.h>

struct A {
    explicit A(char*) { }
};

struct B {
    B(nullptr_t a) = delete;
    B(char*) { }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a(0);         // darnit I compiled...
    B b1(0);        // good, fails, but with only b/c ambiguous
    B b2((char*)0); // good, succeeds
    B b3(1);        // good, fails, with correct error
}
```

Is there a better way than this?  Also, what exactly is delete accomplishing here?

Comment: Not a C++ expert here, but I'd imagine if you want to stop your constructors from taking an int, you'd want to delete `B(int)`.

Comment: @user2357112 that's not what OP wants. He wants to avoid the specific corner case where the integer constant 0 is converted to a null pointer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Does deleting `B(int)` not handle that?

Comment: @user2357112: YES, that seems to do the trick.  I'll try it out for awhile and see what happens.   Make that an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: gcc has a warning flag which you could set to be an error when compiling. VC++ probably has a similar warning.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting `A(int)` will not prevent `A(char *)` being called with
`nullptr`. So you will need to delete `A(nullptr_t)` as well.

And even this will not protect you from the eventuality that
there is some rogue class in the neighbourhood that is
implicitly constructible from 0 or `nullptr` and
implicitly converts same to `char *`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int) = delete;
    A(std::nullptr_t) = delete;
    explicit A(char * p) {
        std::cout << "Constructed with p = " << (void *)p << std::endl;
    }
};

struct X
{
    X(long i) : _i(i) {}
    operator char *() const { return (char *)_i; }
    long _i;
};

int main()
{
    X x(0);
    A a(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints:

```
Constructed with p = 0
```

You may reckon that possibility remote enough to be ignored;
or you might prefer to delete *all* constructors,
in one fell swoop, whose argument is not precisely of a type
that you sanction. E.g. assuming the sanctioned types are just `char *`:

```
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    A(T) = delete;
    explicit A(char * p) {}
};

struct X
{
    X(long i) : _i(i) {}
    operator char *() const { return (char *)_i; }
    long _i;
};

int main()
{
    // A a0(0);
    //A a1(nullptr);
    X x(0);
    // A a2(x);
    char *p = x;
    A a3(p); // OK     
    return 0;
}
```

Here all of the commented out constructor calls fail to compile.

Comment: It doesn't seem like blocking an explicit call with `nullptr` is desired; it seems like more of an unpleasant side effect.

Comment: Does deleting with a template work for you? template<typename T>
    A(T) = delete;  I have read that templated copy constructors don't disqualify default constructors.  I have experienced it too.  So deleting them has no effect.

Comment: I would like char* to be called with nullptr, just not some enum that happened to be 0, which is what was happening to me!  I was not clear on this in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop your constructor from taking `0`, one option would be to delete `B(int)`:

```
B(int) = delete;
```

That's an unambiguously better match for `B(0)` than the constructor that takes a `char *`.

Note that up until C++11, `NULL` was specified as being of integer type, and even in C++11 and later, it's still likely implemented as `#define NULL 0`. `B(NULL)` won't work if you do this. `B(nullptr)` will work, but still, I'd be wary of whether this is worth doing.

Comment: I think this works for my problem.   The compiler looks at a 0 and says it could also be a void*.  It then looks at the constructors.  If it finds a int constructor it prefers that, sees the delete and stops.